# Feynman diagram using tikz-feynman package has wrong size

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynman

I have a simple question comming the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% lualatex
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[fermion] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [fermion] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [ghost] c, 
b  -- [ghost] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [blue, gluon] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to d] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [blue, gluon] d,
b  -- [blue, gluon] e,
};

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The forth diagram is a litle bit bigger than the others, as can be seen here:

[image]

How should I proceed in order to make all the diagrams have the same size?

Comment: Yeah, the fourth diagram needs to be the same size as the others, or else you'll break gauge invariance.

Comment: @Buzz, as well as the Poincare invariance!

Comment: I am afraid that the only thing I was ruinning was my master thesis wonderfull look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use tools like `\resizebox` or similar to scale the diagram. This will change the line width and size of the dot and will make your thesis look like a ransom letter.

Instead you could nudge the coordinates a bit to move in the right direction:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
% lualatex
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[fermion] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [fermion] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [ghost] c, 
b  -- [ghost] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [blue, gluon] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to d] {
a[shift={(0.1cm,-0.1cm)}] --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c[shift={(-0.2cm,0.2cm)}], 
b  -- [blue, gluon] d[shift={(-0.2cm,-0.1cm)}],
b  -- [blue, gluon] e[shift={(0.1cm,0.2cm)}],
};

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively use the tikz scale option, which will leave the line width, dot size etc. intact:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
% lualatex
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[fermion] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [fermion] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [ghost] c, 
b  -- [ghost] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [blue, gluon] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to d,scale=0.95] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [blue, gluon] d,
b  -- [blue, gluon] e,
};

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed that problem as soon as I re-scaled the 4th diagram... This is in fact the correct way to solve issue!

Comment: @Tr909T You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scalerel` package with the option `\scaleobj` to zoom in or out.  The value is **.87**.

```
\documentclass{article}
% lualatex
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[fermion] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [fermion] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [ghost] c, 
b  -- [ghost] d
};
\qquad
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to b] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [blue, gluon] d
};
\qquad
\scaleobj{.87}{\feynmandiagram [inline=(b), horizontal=a to d] {
a --[blue, gluon] b [dot]  -- [blue, gluon] c, 
b  -- [blue, gluon] d,
b  -- [blue, gluon] e,
};}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A simple solution to a simple problem! Great! 
Thanks!